# How to deal with "HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request" Jenkins?

Tags: python, rest, jenkins, post, python-requests

I try to abort Jenkins job build using python requests. This is my python code:

```
    crumb_value = (
        requests.get(f"https://{usr}:{psw}@<jenkins url>/crumbIssuer/api/json", verify=False)).json()["crumb"]
    jenkins_abort = requests.post(f"https://{usr}:{psw}@<job url>/stop",
                                 json={'Jenkins-Crumb': crumb_json}, verify=False)
```

So firstly I use Get request to get crumb value (this works correctly). Then I send a Post request to abort jenkins build, I include in it json file with proper crumb field name and it's value, but strangly I get output like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/<job url>/stop</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.43.v20210629</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

I've read some stack overflow issues and think that I do what I'm supposed to but it doesn't work. I'll highly appreciate any suggestions on my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my issue. It turned out that you need to send Get request for crumb and Post request to abort build from same session. The code, that works for me:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (usr, psw)

crumb_json = (session.get("https://<jenkins host url>/crumbIssuer/api/json", verify=False)).json()

    jenkins_abort = session.post("https://<job url>/stop", headers={'Jenkins-Crumb': f"{crumb_json['crumb']}"},
                                 json=crumb_json, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using a Python library like [api4jenkins](https://pypi.org/project/api4jenkins/) so you don't have to worry about passing the Crumbs?

Since you are getting a Certificate validation error you can either upgrade your certificate to a CA-signed cert or disable it.

```
jenkins = Jenkins(url, username, password, ssl_verify=False)
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/pycontribs/jenkinsapi/blob/master/doc/source/ssl_certificate_verification).

Comment: Using api4jenkins I get ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED], is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: The answer you gave is on how to disable ssl_verify in jenkinsapi library, not in api4jenkins. In api4jenkins there is no way to disable it. Also I've already tried using jenkinsapi library and it doesn't work for me since disable() func in it strangly doesn't abort my job build (the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085662/python-jenkinsapi-disable-enable-a-job-not-working))

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/joelee2012/api4jenkins/issues/59)  is a post on how to disable SSL verify on api4jenkins